# [SOVLED]PDO/MySQL Prepared Statement Injection Semi Colon

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, escaping, code-injection

i was wondering why in my prepared statement some characters from formular user input aren't escaped as i would expect it to be. here is my code at this particular part:

```
if( isset( $_POST['key'] ) && strlen($_POST['key']) <= 15) {
    $sql = "SELECT titel, date, content FROM News WHERE content LIKE :content OR titel LIKE :title";
    if( $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql) ) {
        $temp = "%".$_POST['key']."%"; // NOT manually escaped here
        $stmt->bindParam(':content', $temp); // should escape!?
        $stmt->bindParam(':title', $temp); // should escape!?
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bindColumn("Titel", $title, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindColumn("Datum", $date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindColumn("Inhalt", $content, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        while( $stmt->fetch() ) {
            echo "<span class='head'>".$title." :: ".$date."</span><br />".shorten($content)."...<br /><hr>"; // the function shorten just shortens the content for preview reasons
        }

        // ends statement
        $stmt = NULL;

        // ends connection
        $pdo = NULL;
    }
    else {
        $err .= "statement wasn't prepare()'ed!";
    }
}
else {
    $err .= "no or false input!";
}
```

So this basically works alright, but when i enter ';' for example it just throws out every result. so im' not sure if it really escapes the input properly. am i missing sth or are there not all characters escaped? if so which are they? i would rather escape them manually.

Comment: What do you mean by 'it throws out every result'? It returns everything, even rows where content and title don't include a `;`?

Comment: The only characters that should need to be escaped inside a `LIKE` argument are `%`, `_`, and backslash

Comment: add `PDO::PARAM_STR` to the `bindParam` and test again

Comment: yes, all rows even if the content doesn't contain the ;. @akam i'll try this out now

Comment: According to the documentation, `PDO::PARAM_STR` is the default, so that probably won't help.

Comment: barmar is quite right, i edited it (also here) but it didn't work

Comment: I wonder who would upvote this question where intermixed sql injections (which actually absent here), escaping (which not required here) and some silly mistake in the code/tests which is responsible for the wrong(?) output

Comment: btw, i do have some small basic knowlegde about sql injections, and there are some possibilites where a simple OR 1=1 does the deal without the need for widlcards(%,_)

Comment: yes, and i was escaped properly. still the ; is getting on my nerves. there is no wrong output. just too much when i enter a ; everything that is contained in that table is contained in the result

Comment: @YourCommonSense: can you please explain what is wrong here!!!!!!!! other wise stop your mouse to click on downvote and write a comment at least!

Comment: i'm actually still interested in the silly mistakes. because if there is, i would want them to be fixed. maybe you can just say which lines you mean and write a solution which would be right in your opinion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was wondering why in my prepared statement some characters from formular user input aren't escaped as i would expect it to be.

Because your expectations are wrong.
Prepared statement is not necessarily involve any escaping at all
Even if so - a honest semicolon character is totally harmless, and require no escaping at all.

> PDO/MySQL Prepared Statement Injection

There is no possible injection in your code, it is perfectly safe.

> when i enter ';' for example it just throws out every result.

That's another question, irrelevant to injections and escaping. Double-check your data and other premises.

By the way, to shorten your code a bit

```
$sql  = "SELECT titel, date, content FROM News WHERE content LIKE ? OR titel LIKE ?";
$temp = "%".$_POST['key']."%";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($temp,$temp));
while( $row = $stmt->fetch() ) {
    extract($row);
    echo "<span class='head'>$titel :: $date</span><br />".shorten($content)."...<br /><hr>"; 
}
```

Comment: okay, i found the problem, it was indeed about double-checking data. due to the fact that german ÖÄÜöäüß are stored as &Xuml; or &szlig; in the database there are many ;. and of course this isn't visible because they are displayed as actual characters then

Comment: I also shortened your code a bit, as there was too much useless commands